# Dynamics CRM port 1025 use

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am just trying to figure out what uses port 1025 in Dynamics CRM. The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699823(v=crm.5).aspx) states that the port is used for "DCOM, used as an RPC listener." The documentation is not clear on what it is used for and which direction this port is needed (inbound or outbound). When monitoring the server with wireshark I cannot see anything using this port.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Deleted my answer, overlooked the additional comments in the paragraph which mentions the port range is only valid for server 2003. The new default start and end ports are 49152 - 65535, unless you have a mixed server environment.

Comment: all servers involved are 2008 r2 or higher.